# Use multiple patterns in an element XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define an element with multiple patterns, like `gDay`, `gMonth`, `gYear`, `dateTime`, etc. How can I define a restriction in **XSD** to do that?

Someting like this:

```
<dates>
    <out>2012</out>
</dates>


<xs:complexType name="infodates">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="out" type="xs:dateTime"&"xs:gMonth"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should post examples of what valid XML would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: xml schema can't concatenate simple datatypes.

It might not be what you want anyway: `xs:gMonth` requires a double-hyphen prefix (e.g. "--05"), and `xs:gDay` needs a triple-hyphen (e.g. "---31"). Not what I expected!
Here's [examples for each simple datatype](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#CreatDt). There's some combined types built-in too: `gYearMonth`, `gMonthDay` etc.

Along these lines, [`xs:dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#dateTime-lexical-representation) has a long definition: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`  Only three parts can be left out, so it needs `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` - your example in `<out>2012</out>` isn't valid with respect to this.

---

Long answer: However, xml schema *can* combine simple datatypes by `union` (like choice) and `list` (space-separated list of the same type). So, you can do something like: `(gDay|gMonth|gYear|dateTime)*` (not valid xsd syntax, just illustrative). This isn't ordered and allows duplicates, so e.g. "---31 --05 --05" is valid. Here it is in xsd syntax:

```
$ cat catDatatypes.xsd 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="eg" type="myString_Type"/>
  <xs:simpleType name="myString_Type">
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:union>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:gDay"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:gMonth"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:gYear"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:union>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>

$ xmllint --schema catDatatypes.xsd catDatatypes.xml 
<eg>2012 --12 ---01 --12 ---31 --05 --05</eg>
catDatatypes.xml validates
```

Conclusion: You can't reuse the built-in datatypes in the way you (and I) would like, and they don't seem very nice anyway. You're probably better off explicitly defining it yourself, as in InfantProgrammer'Aravind's answer. (Or, you could use separate attributes for each component instead - which would make it easier for whoever is parsing it, too).

---

For fun, I tried shortening InfantProgrammer'Aravind's answer (though it's arguable whether this makes it clearer...). It retains the check of 12-hour with am/pm vs. 24-hour without am/pm (but doesn't accept empty aka null value).

```
 <xs:simpleType name="CRNDATETIME2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/([12]\d{3}) ((0\d|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){2}|(0\d|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){2} [aApP][mM])"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Here's a [brief guide](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#regexAppendix) to regex in XSD; here's a [long one](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#regexs).

BTW: Turns out you can denote "[1-9]" as "[\d-[0]]", which is a ["Character Class *Subtraction*"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#nt-charClassSub), not a range.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done having custom pattern as TYPE..
example:

```
     <xs:simpleType name="CRNDATETIME">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="|(((01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ](00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23)[:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9])|
                             ((01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)/(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ](01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)[:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9] [aApP][mM]))"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
```

this accepts datetime value of below patterns 
 1. MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss aAmM/pPmM .. 
 2. MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss 

 also accepts null value ..

I know it would be bit difficult rather very difficult.. but achievable ..